# How to Update Columns on Replica Only

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.26 and I have a primary-replica setup. My goal is to automatically update a column in a replica to the current timestamp when a new row is inserted or a row is updated on the table.

This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cus_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then on the replica, I added this column and created these triggers:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN updated_at timestamp;

CREATE TRIGGER t1__before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.updated_at = NOW();

CREATE TRIGGER t1__before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.updated_at = NOW();
```

But then when I tried to insert new data or update an existing row on the primary, the trigger was not invoked on the replica. This means the updated_at column on the replica remains null. Any ideas on how I can tell the replica to run these triggers or update this column when an insert/update happens on this table?

Note: the binlog_format is "ROW".

Comment: It would be much easier if you updated the timestamp(s) on both servers -- Please explain why you need the servers to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just run the ALTER TABLE on the Primary ???

That way, there is no need for stored procedures on the replica (which usually do not fire off on a replica anyway when the binlog_format is ROW).

Use pt-online-schema-change on the primary.

Here is a bash script to get you started

```
HN=IPAddressofPrimaryDBHost
DB=mydb
TB=t1

RUNMODE=0
[ "${1}" == "live" ] && RUNMODE=1
[ ${RUNMODE} -eq 0 ] && PTOSC_OPERATION=--dry-run && TAG=test
[ ${RUNMODE} -eq 1 ] && PTOSC_OPERATION=--execute && TAG=live
RUNLOG=ptosc-${TAG}.log
ALTER_TABLE_SQL="ADD COLUMN updated_at timestamp"
PTOSC_OPTIONS="--print"

pt-online-schema-change -F my.cnf h=${HN},D=${DB},t=${TB} --alter "${ALTER_TABLE_SQL}" ${PTOSC_OPTIONS} ${PTOSC_OPERATION} >${RUNLOG} 2>&1

mysql --defaults-file=my.cnf -D${DB} -Ae"show create table ${TB}\G"
```

Here is a sample `my.cnf`

```
[client]
user = root
password = whateverpassword
```

Comment: The table in the primary is a "hot" table (essentially this table is used by the site literally for everything) and it contains 5 billion rows. I tried to run pt-osc in a staging environment and it took a day or so even with a sysbench simulating tons of read/write. 

In your experience, do you think pt-osc can work with "hot" tables in the primary instance? Would it have some performance implications? Also, I am thinking that if I run pt-osc and I am not happy with it, I could just kill pt-osc and everything should be back to normal. But again, I am hesitant because this is our "hot" table.

Comment: @BrianEstrada Boy I feel your pain. I had a 13TB table that I ran ptosc and it took 6 months to finish. Spent 2 months deleting 8 billion rows beforehand. I got the file shrunk to 3.75TB.

Comment: @BrianEstrada Yes, pt-osc can handle a hot table. If you feel there will be a performance impact, you can just launch pt-osc with `--pause-file` to suspend performing the change and you delete the pause file to continue.  About 3 years ago, there was a very hot table that I paused during business hours (9AM-6PM) and resumed after business hours. That particular pt-osc took 3 days.

Comment: One caveat: If you start pt-osc and you kill it, you must dropthe temp table it creates and remove the three triggers it creatres on the source table.

Comment: Thank you! I am more relieved and excited to run pt-osc now.